# Comparing two datasets with different structures but similar fields

Tags: excel, powerbi

I work for a home based education program and we are trying to find a way to make comparing our two tracking systems easier. Unfortunately due to limitations within the software we are using for this, we cannot combine it all into one place. I have two different data sets that share some fields but are for two different things. The first set is for documenting that a visit to the home occurred or not. The second set documents what happened during that visit. Both datasets have include a date field and a field for the child's name.

[table_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viswa.png) [table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDEDr.png)

I've included a sample version of each table. There are other columns but they are unique to each data set. The ultimate goal is to be able to ensure that the information is being documented into both systems. I had thought to utilize the name or date field to link the data sets together to identify discrepancies but haven't had much success as of yet.

Basically I need to make sure that if a visit occurred on 4/5/21 than it was documented to both places and if it wasn't, identify which area is missing the information. It would be nice to be able to also then summarize the information by child.

I've tried Power BI and Power Query in Excel but to be honest I'm not even sure how to phrase my question in order to find the proper way to do this from Google.

Comment: You want a full outer join on your key fields when using merge in powerBI. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/merge-queries-full-outer  basically define query 1 data set, define query 2 data set.  Merge on key fields, set to full outer, and then make sure you bring in all fields from both queries.  Then use filters in excel to show only those where actual date is blank on one data set or the other.  Those are your problem records.  as far as "Summarize" that depends on what result you're after.  It could be a pivot table... or something else... need more info to know

Comment: Thank you for your help! That helped get me a bit further. After doing the full outer join I realized that using either just the name or just the date was causing duplication because both would appear multiple times in both tables. I created a custom column to combine the name and the date to create a unique key for each record but now when I merge the two tables, Power BI is not merging everything. I'm getting 63 rows of 232 from table 1 and 63 of 2152 from table 2. Any suggestions on how I can view the rows not included to identify what's causing them to be excluded?

Comment: that sounds like it's doing inner join  make sure it's doing an outer and 63 match but it shows all data from both tables..  In the resulting data set which should have 232+2142-(63 since both have 63 matches we exclude 1 set of 63 as all the others didn't match) rows.... add a column which checks to see if the name and date of 1 matches the name and date of another if it does return 1 else 0.  then filter on the zeros.  Make sure you're showing all columns from both data sets (6+4) 10 total; based on images.

Comment: There may be an easier way to do this in powerBI but I'm not as familiar with it as I am with SQL in general (which is what the left, inner, outer relates to)